# local node while executing all transaction in the newly monted block found out that one transaction does not yield the correct results

Tags: mining

From: https://medium.com/blockchannel/life-cycle-of-an-ethereum-transaction-e5c66bae0f6e

"Eventually your local node will receive this new block and syncs it’s local copy of the blockchain. Upon receiving the new block, the local node executes all the transactions in the block."

What happens if the local node while executing all transaction in the newly monted block found out that one transaction does not yield the correct results? Different execution results from other nodes

Comment: Can you please further explain what do you mean by "correct results"? Double spends? If you're using other OPCODES than the network, nobody will accept your blocks, as you mandate a different gas pricing.

Comment: yes or invalid signatures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a block contains an invalid transaction, or the execution of all transactions do not match the `stateRoot` field in the block header the block header is marked as invalid.

The changes caused by executing all transactions are discarded. The Ethereum World state is returned to the previous state, before the block was evaluated, as the block was never submitted.

An ethereum client can take additional measure like blacklisting nodes that send invalid blocks for example.

Comment: this answer is great -- you are a great guy